# How to enable Split Screen Icon?

Tags: visual-studio-code, split-screen

I accidently deleted the "Split Screen" icon on the top right side of the VS Code, idk how to get it back I tried all methods I could find. Please tell me how to get that icon back, a video or photo tutorial would be great. Thank you

I asked users of VS Code over discord, Searched VS Code documents, but I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 3):

Click with right mouse button on `...` (More Actions ...) on the top right side of VS Code and select "Reset Menu".

Answer (score 0):

To hide icon: Right click on icon and select "Hide 'Split Editor Right'".
To bring back icon: Right click on tab bar and select "Split Editor Right".
[Context menu to hide/enable icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSiqf.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).